# JSF 2.0 - selectOneMenu defaults to 0 when empty

Tags: jsf-2, drop-down-menu, java-ee-6, converters, selectonemenu

For my project i want to implement a combobox with **h:selectOneMenu**. I read many posts about how to handle the selectOneMenu properly and how to implement a custom converter. The combobox shall store the ID (**Long**) from a different DB Table (named fk_ID) for which a constrain is in place. So far everything seems to function as planned. Now to my problem:

The column fk_ID is optional, so the first option in the combobox is a **f:selectItem** with no value labeled "choose ...". When I save the form and change the value everything is OK, except if I set it back to "choose ...". The error I get is a **constraint integrity violation**.

I found the problem too: The converter returns **null** as intended but the bean receives the **Long 0**.

The XHTML:

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{userBean.selectedModel.fk_id}"
    id="combobox">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="choose ..." />
    <f:selectItems
        value="#{userBean.items}"
        var="item"
        itemLabel="#{item.value}"
        itemValue="#{item.id}"
    />
    <f:converter converterId="userConverter" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

The custom converter:

```
@FacesConverter(value = "userConverter")
public class UserConverter implements Converter {
    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext arg0, UIComponent arg1, String arg2) {
        if (arg2 != null && !arg2.equals("null"))
            return Long.valueOf(arg2);

        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext arg0, UIComponent arg1, Object arg2) {
        return String.valueOf(arg2);
    }
}
```

The bean (very short version):

```
@Named(value = "userBean")
public class UserController implements Serializable {

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private UserModel selectedModel;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private List<UserModel> items;

    public void saveModel() {
        selectedModel = userService.saveModel(selectedModel);
    }
}
```

The problem is that the **fk_id** is **Long 0**, but should be **null**. I can solve the problem by writing

```
if (selectedModel.getFk_id() == 0)
    selectedModel.setFk_id(null);
```

, but thats not a solution I am comfortable with.

My Question: Why is the value **null**, which the converter returns, the **Long 0** inside the **saveModel()** method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This converter is unnecessary and makes no sense (I'd expect an `UserConverter` to convert between `User` and `String`, not between `Long` and `String`). Remove it.

Now, you need to tell JSF to interpret empty string submitted values as `null`. Add the following to your `web.xml`:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

This should solve the problem on most containers. But if you're using Tomcat or a fork/clone of it (JBoss AS, WebSphere AS, etc) and/or the container uses the Apache EL parser implementation, then you also need to add the following argument to its VM startup arguments:

```
-Dorg.apache.el.parser.COERCE_TO_ZERO=false
```

This will prevent the Apache EL parser from coercing the submitted value to the primitive's default, even though you're using a primitive wrapper type as property.

#### See also:

- [Communication in JSF 2.0](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html)

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, you don't have a combobox there. That's just a simple dropdownlist. A combobox is an editable dropdownlist. Get your terms right ;)

Comment: A dropdown list indeed ;) . The problem was solved exactly as you said. For I am using a Tomcat server, I even needed to include the argument at startup. Thanks a lot!