# selectOneMenu default value issue using converter

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, converters

I'm using `<p:selectOneMenu>` as follows:

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="choixProgramme" converter="#{programmeConverter}"
value="#{programmeController.selectedProgramme}">
<f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="" />
<f:selectItems value="#{programmeController.listProgrammes}"
    var="programme" itemLabel="#{programme.codeProgImmobilier}"
    itemValue="#{programme}" />
<p:ajax update="dataTableBien" />
```

I would like to show `Select One` message, but I get this error:

```
java.lang.String cannot be cast to xx.xxxxx.xxxx.xxxx.dto.ProgrammeDto
```

I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8093932/jsf-2-0-selectonemenu-defaults-to-0-when-empty) but I still have the same problem.

**Edited**

I added `noSelectionOption` to my `<f:selectItem>`:

But I have a conversation problem in `getAsObject()`.

```
 java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Select One"
```

**Edited**

My converter:

```
@Override
public Object getAsObject(FacesContext arg0, UIComponent arg1, String arg2) {
    if (arg2 == null || arg2.isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    }

    String programme = arg2;
    Long value = Long.valueOf(programme);
    ProgrammeDto result = new ProgrammeDto();
    result = programmeService.findById(value);
    return result;
}

@Override
public String getAsString(FacesContext arg0, UIComponent arg1, Object arg2) {

    if (arg2 == null) {
        return "";
    }
    if(arg2 instanceof ProgrammeDto) {
        if (((ProgrammeDto) arg2).getIdProgramme() == null) {
            return "";
        }
    }

            ProgrammeDto programme = new ProgrammeDto();

    if(arg2 instanceof ProgrammeDto) {

        programme = (ProgrammeDto) arg2;
        String codeProgramme = programme.getIdProgramme().toString();
        return (codeProgramme != null) ? String.valueOf(codeProgramme) : null;
    } else throw new ConverterException("Something wrong!" + arg2.hashCode() + arg2.toString());

}
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You're specifying an item value of an empty string and you've most likely the following in your converter's `getAsString()`:

```
public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object modelValue) {
    return ((ProgrammeDto) modelValue).getId();
}
```

However, an empty string can never be represented as a valid `ProgrammeDto` reference.

Either use an item value of `#{null}` instead of an empty string:

```
<f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="#{null}" />
```

or set the `noSelectionOption` attribute to `true`:

```
<f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" noSelectionOption="true" />
```

Chances are that the converter's `getAsString()` will now throw `NullPointerException` instead of `ClassCastException`, but it should be obvious enough as to how to fix that. Just check if it's not null before casting and obtaining the desired field.

```
public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object modelValue) {
    return (modelValue != null) ? ((ProgrammeDto) modelValue).getId() : null;
}
```

#### See also:

- [Confused with PrimeFaces Converter (as it applies to selectOneMenu)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18818517/confused-with-primefaces-converter-as-it-applies-to-selectonemenu/18854677#18854677)

---

**Update**: as per your updated question, it seems that PrimeFaces is not considering the `noSelectionOption` and treating label as item value. In that case, you'd need to either explicitly specify an item value of `#{null}`:

```
<f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="#{null}" noSelectionOption="true" />
```

or to check in the `getAsObject()` if the submitted value is parseable as a `Long`:

```
if (arg2 == null || !arg2.matches("[0-9]+")) {
    return null;
}
```

Comment: I still have the same problem, I think the problem is that PrimeFaces is treating label as item value like you said. But if you can see my second update, I think that's not the best solution, but it works.

Comment: What if you just use `itemValue="#{null}"`?

Comment: It returns the label not the value too!

Comment: That's not so nice from PrimeFaces. I'd go ahead with checking if the submitted value is parseable as `Long` as shown in updated answer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41556/discussion-between-safwen-khalloufi-and-balusc)